# Limiting function of $e^{-nx}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=e^{-nx}$ on the interval [0,1]. Explain why the sequence of functions {$f_n$} converges pointwise on [0,1]. What is the limiting function and is it continuous? Is the convergence uniform?

I think I have an intuitive idea of how to do this, but formalizing it and the portion on uniform convergence trip me up.

Comment: Can you find the pointwise limit?

Comment: Would the pointwise limit just be e--when x=0?

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $f(x)=e^{-nx}$ converges pointwise, pick a fixed x first. If $x = 0$, $f(x)=1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. If $x>0$, $f(x)=0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. So $f(x)$ does converges pointwise. Now the limiting function is not continuous at $0$ as you can see.

The idea of uniformly convergent is that your convergence does not depend on $x$. As far as the intuition goes, think about they gave you any large number $N$, as you pick $x$ close enough to zero, $f_n(x)$ will approach $1$ eventually as $x$ gets close enough to $0$, which makes it impossible to make $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$

Comment: I agree with the first paragraph, but not the second is obtuse. To me uniform convergence would imply that f(1) - f(2) = f(2) - f(3) = f(3) - f(4) and so on. That obviously isn't so since you would be summing a finite quantity an infinite number of times. Such a sum  would be unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

First, We need to observe that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-nx}=\begin{cases}
1,x=0\\
0,x\in (0,1]
\end{cases}
$$
Thus the limiting function is not continuous at $x=0$. In addition,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{-n \times (1/n)}=e^{-1},
$$
which means that it doesn't converges uniformly. In fact,
$$
\exists \epsilon=e^{-1}, \forall \delta>0, |e^{-n\times (1/n)}-0|=e^{-1}\ge \epsilon
$$

Comment: You don't even need the example that converges to $e^{-1}$. If convergence were uniform, the limit would be continuous, per the [uniform limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem).